# JQuery: Get specific values from multiple anchor binding?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
var myCode = {};

(function( global ) {
     global.print = function(value){
                   alert("Values: " + value);
                }
            })(myCode);


$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('[id^=el]').bind("click", function(e) {
        myCode.print("Value");
    });

});
```

I have this list of anchor elements:

```
<li>
    <a id="el1"><h3>header 1</h3><p>paragraph 1</p></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="el2"><h3>header 2</h3><p>paragraph 2</p></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="el3"><h3>header 3</h3><p>paragraph 3</p></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="el4"><h3>header 4</h3><p>paragraph 4</p></a>
</li>
```

How can I bind multiple elements withou writing the binding one 
If anchor `el4` is clicked I want to print `Values: header 4, paragraph 4`
So how can I get in `Jquery` the header or paragraph of the respective anchor that is clicked on?

Comment: For one, your HTML isn't valid. You can't nest block-level elements inside of inline elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this would do it, you need to grab the text value of the h3 & paragraph tags inside of each anchor you're clicking.

```
$('[id^="el"]').bind("click", function(e) {
    myCode.print($(this).find('h3').text() + ', ' + $(this).find('p').text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

***HTML***

```
<li>
    <a id="el1"><h3>header 1</h3><p>paragraph 1</p></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="el2"><h3>header 2</h3><p>paragraph 2</p></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="el3"><h3>header 3</h3><p>paragraph 3</p></a>
</li>
<li>
    <a id="el4"><h3>header 4</h3><p>paragraph 4</p></a>
</li>
```

***JS CODE***

```
var myCode = {};

(function( global ) {
     global.print = function(value){
                   alert("Values: " + value);
                }
            })(myCode);


$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('[id^=el]').bind("click", function(e) {
        myCode.print($(this).find('h3').text()+ '  '+ $(this).find('p').text());
    });

});
```

Comment: I want to get them separatelly, like the other answer that does it  with find()

Comment: sorry i can't see you in time.

Comment: Today I finished the votes but tomorrow I will have some again :)